# Search for two duplicated matches in 3 columns (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Is it possible to check 3 columns in Excel and if two columns' value is duplicated, then highlight or give back a boolean? 
Like the picture on the link (I also added the logic I based my question on).
Or is it more like a VBA-question?
Thanks a lot!

[image: Excel and logic]

Comment: Are you sure your example is correct? Row 2, column 3 has the value `c` and I see `c` the the row right above it, therefore it would have a duplicate. What you describe can be done with conditional formatting

Comment: Do the values have to be in the same columns both times to be considered as duplicates?

Comment: So, it has to match 2 columns out of the 3. 
Because of this, @cybernetic.nomad , the C is not duplicate becase it has no other column to match with.

Comment: @TomSharpe , yes they have to be in the same columns. 
Thanks for helping guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

[image]

Formula in `D1`:

```
=IF(LARGE(MMULT(--(A$1:C$4=A1:C1),{1,1,1}),2)>1,"HASDUP","NO")
```

Drag down.

---

Edit: It works even with empty cells.

[image]

And in the case you don't want to count cells when empty then use:

```
=IF(LARGE(MMULT((A$1:C$4=A2:C2)*(A2:C2<>""),{1,1,1}),2)>1,"HASDUP","NO")
```

[image]

Comment: Btw, if you have an error, please try to change the commas in the `{1,1,1}`-array to backslash chars. I always forget the en-US notation.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help, this sounds good, but it gives #Value! error, both as 
 ` =IF(LARGE(MMULT(--(A$1:C$4=A1:C1),{1,1,1}),2)>1,"HASDUP","NO") ` and ` {1/1/1}  `.
I have tried it to format it as text also as general, but neither of them did the trick.
Im trying to hunt down the issue, but any help is appreciated, I have a bit hangover :)

Comment: What is your Excel's locale language? @kandzsem

Comment: the editing language is English ( United States ) . 
But I just found that: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mmult-function-40593ed7-a3cd-4b6b-b9a3-e4ad3c7245eb, which says:  MMULT returns the #VALUE! error when:
Any cells are empty or contain text.

So the MMULT is not for me (because I need text). But thanks anyway!

Comment: @kandzsem, that is **not** the issue! Even with empty cells or cells with text this will work since it's about the boolean structure inside the 2nd parameter returning either false/true values which are not empty and can be used as numeric input. See the edit. Both text/empty values used and returns the correct output.

Comment: thanks for the help, but unfortunately it's still the same. You were right though, i've tried with numbers too, it did not work.

Comment: However, Im european, so the excel might pick up the OS language, even it's not set to do so, how should I modify the function to work ?

Comment: Yes, so what is your locale language in the OS? @kandzsem. Meanwhile, try `=IF(LARGE(MMULT((A$1:C$4=A1:C1)*(A1:C1<>""),MOD(ROW($1:$3),1)+1),2)>1,"HASDUP","NO")`

Comment: It works now, thanks a lot! It has some flaws, but it might be just my logic, but it's 99% perfect and reduced ~1000 lines to 350, which is a big help :) Thanks again, I owe you one! :)

Comment: I also just thought it could be improved by telling which columns are matching, but that's another topic I think :)

Comment: Yes, @kandzsem, that's a nice follow-up question here on SO =). Glad it finally worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple rule for conditional formatting each of the possible pairs of columns A & B, A & C, B & C which are listed in columns E to F:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$4,A1,$B$1:$B$4,B1)>1
```

and similarly for the other three columns.

E2 is just

```
a1&b1
```

[image]

You could use a single rule for all three columns but probably not worth the bother:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX($A$1:$C$4,0,COLUMN(A1)),A1,INDEX($A$1:$C$4,0,MOD(COLUMN(A1),3)+1),INDEX($A1:$C1,MOD(COLUMN(A1),3)+1 ))>1
```

---

Here is a larger simulation where I've generated about 500 different letter pairs and distributed them among 900 rows. The first one is using three separate formulas and the second one is using the combined formula (both as above but extended to 900 rows):

[image]

And here is where it's repeated

[image]

If your data is fairly random, you shouldn't get many duplicates...but it could be that with real data there are too many duplicates to make conditional formatting like this a viable proposition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but the original excel has ~900 rows with ~400-500 unique values, so it would be hard to combine all the possible scenarios for it. 
But thanks a lot for trying!

Comment: Number of rows or unique values shouldn't matter as long as there are only three columns. When I get chance I will test it on ~900 rows and ~500 unique values and get back to you.

Comment: Have posted larger simulation and it looks fine with pseudo-random data.